# TextField Issue - Android Keyboard wont function

Tags: java, javafx-8, javafxports

I developed a simple javafx application to be ported in Android Environment, however I cant type any characters in the `TextField`. I guess its a bug, how to fix this one?

**build.gradle:**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.0.7'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

mainClassName = 'com.ras.Main'

jfxmobile {
    android {
        manifest = 'lib/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
    ios {
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
    }
}

jfxmobile {
    android {
        packagingOptions {
        exclude 'build.properties'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {    
    compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: '*.jar')
}
```

**JDK:**

```
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
```

**Android Phone:**

```
Samsung Galaxy J2
```

Comment: I guess you've also written some code?

Comment: It worked in Samsung Galaxy SM-T705, but not in Samsung Galaxy J2.  :)